Interpretation of a commutation relation
I am not a mathematician, therefore, I have not had too much to do with Lie algebras and am just revising some concepts for my PhD project.
If you had a Lie algebra, in this case the $\mathfrak{sl}_d$ Lie algebra over the complex numbers. And you know its generating set, which would in this case just be the generalized Pauli elements $P\in\mathcal{P}_d$ according to the Silvester representation, without the identity (so, not Hermitian). If I knew for some set of matrices ${M_i}\in \mathfrak{sl}_d$, the commutation relation
$[M_i, P]\neq 0$
for all Pauli elements and all $M_i$, what does this indicate about the $M_i$? How do I interpret this?

Usually the fact that some Lie brackets are not zero does not indicate much.

you can write your $M_i$ in terms of $P$ (since they generate the algebra) and plug that back into the bracket. maybe things will become clearer then, but as is, nothing much can be said.

And what if both, ${M_i}_i$ was a generating set for this algebra and $\mathcal{P}_d$ spanned this algebra? Because this would be precisely the situation. Does this help?

@paulina OK now I got a really basic question, I'm sorry: If i want to express my matrix $M_i$ that resides in the space of traceless matrices in terms of $P_i$, how would I do that? Since, $\mathrm{Tr}(P_i^\dagger M_j)=0$ or not? Isn't the product of traceless matrices also traceless? How would i then write the inner product here?

the product of traceless matrices need not be traceless, see for example the pauli matrices which are traceless but square to the identity.
